# How to get rid of backslash("\")character from a string

Tags: c#, str-replace

Is there a way, where i can avoid the '\' character from a string ?

```
//bit array
    BitArray b1 = new BitArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("10101010"));
    BitArray b2 = new BitArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("10101010"));

    //Say i perform XOR operation on this 
    b1 = b1.Xor(b2);

    //After the XOR oper the b1 var holds the result 
    //but i want the result to be displayed as 00000000

    //So i convert the bitarray to a byte[] and then to string 
    byte[] bResult = ToByteArray(b1);
    strOutput  = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bResult);
```

### Output

```
    The string strOutput is = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" 
    But the desired output is 00000000
```

where ToByteArray could be a simple method as this

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(BitArray bits)
        {
             byte[] ret = new byte[bits.Length / 8];
             bits.CopyTo(ret, 0);
             return ret;
        }
```

**Alternative 1** : i can ignore the '\' character using regular expressions or string.replace

But is there any other better way to handle such scenarios ?

Comment: What is in your byte array?  \0, if its escaped are null characters.  Are you viewing the string from the debugger?

Comment: Does your b1 contain the number 0? If so, what is it that you want to achieve? The output is - basically - correct since there is no other way to show a binary 0 value as a character!

Comment: @I am not a dinosaur, the array would be `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` to generate the given output.

Comment: The byte array returned by the ToByteArray method is basically {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}. Is there a way i can get the string representation of the same i.e 00000000

Comment: If the bytes are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} would you then want the string to be 12345 aswell or do you want special treatment for 0?

Comment: @alun : yes i want exactly 12345 in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just manipulate values inside a binary row.Instead,as you've given alternatives,use regular expressions or string replace function to get your designated result set.

For example:
By calling an extra method to your code

```
    byte[] bResult = ToByteArray(b1);
    strOutput  = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bResult).Replace("\\\"","");
```

**EDIT:**

I believe in your case normally my answer would work,
**BUT**

```
0 '\0'
```

is also in ASCII character set(only in 0),that means you're given the same string **\0\0\0\0 ..** replacing with backslash character (\)

```
CALL Replace("\0","0")
```

Comment: But even with this i get the result with a backslash.

Comment: @Myra: sorry, stupid me! the string does not contain any \ chars in reality but only binary zeros. so the solution that you forwarded in your edit should work!

Answer (score 1):

```
    string strOutput = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" 
    string strOutput = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(strOutput).Replace("\\\"","");
```

Comment: thanks ..but im aware of this approach but is there any other way apart from this

Comment: Using regex replace on this problem is like.. in germany we say gunning down sparrows with cannons. `string.Replace` does just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "is there a better way to remove backslashes than to use `string.replace` I would say the answer is generally no, but it depends on what you are looking to do.

Are you looking for raw speed?  Do you think the overhead of compiling a regex and applying it is too slow?  Regex engines are generally fairly well optimized and if you use them often give good performance.  You can look at the source code of "replace" functions in various libraries to get an idea of how pros do things.

But I think your question is whether you can write your own string processing function that is faster than a regex replace because you know you can allocate a string buffer of the max size, walk through the input string and copy into the output every character *except* a backslash.  Sure that is a simple loop and maybe the compiler will optimize it to something faster than a regex replace, but who knows?  Generally these programmer-induced optimizations are not worth the trouble (the code is longer and error-prone).  At least, do some profiling if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach( byte b in bResult )
{

   sb.Append( String.Format("{0:00000000}\n", b ) ;
}
```

strOutput = sb.ToString();

I know, something different but I do believe this is more what you want! Since at some point you have to convert from binary to char! If not, you will not know if it is a binary zero value or the ascii represenation of the char 0!

hth

Mario